# Unable to load an image into NSImageView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimageview

I wrote the following and no image comes up.  I displayed the pointer and it comes out as "0".
In the next code block I checked the path and made shore the image was present there.  Still nothing loads.

```
NSImageView *vi = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 220, 220)];
[self.view addSubview:vi];
NSImage *dog = [NSImage imageNamed:@"airnow3.jpg"];
NSLog(@"pointer %d", dog);

[vi setImage:dog];
```

---

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
NSString *currentpath;

filemgr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

currentpath = [filemgr currentDirectoryPath];
NSLog(@"%@", currentpath);
```

Comment: Why don't you set the image before adding the image view to self.view?

Comment: If you want to log a pointer, use `%p`. `NSImage imageNamed` doesn't use `currentDirectoryPath`. Read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1520015-init). Maybe `init?(contentsOf: URL)` does what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `InitWithImage:(NSImage)` instead of `InitWithFrame`

Comment: I have never had a problem with InitWithFrame.  What's wrong with it?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use **UIImageView.**

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10,10,220,220)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"airnow3.jpg"];
[imageView setImage: image];
[self.view addSubview: imageView];
```